# How to put values of all active buttons into one array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the fiddle that represents my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Ognj3n/jLjh9oLm/
Basically, when someone clicks on any of buttons `onclick` function is changing background color of button, so that user knows which button is clicked, but I omitted that part of code in my fiddle. Now I tried to put values of all clicked buttons into one array, in fiddle it should become `value` of `input` element. Tried doing it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('button.clicked').click(function(){
            var clickedButtons= new Array();
            $('button[background-color="rgb(76, 175, 80)"]').each(function(){
                clickedButtons[clickedButtons.length]=this.value;
            });
        });
    });
```

But inside `$('button[background-color="rgb(76, 175, 80)"]').each(function()` nothing is console logging, as if that part of code is not interpreting at all. Please help, I'm stuck

Comment: You don't select them by their style (This just doesn't work - You're actually selecting here buttons with attribute `background-color` with a value of `rgb(76, 175, 80)`), but by a class that set that style to the button instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add the buttons value inside an array, each time a button is pressed you can edit your code like below:

Each time you press a button, I call the `push()` function which adds the element value inside the array.

**Code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   var clickedButtons = new Array();

   $('button.clicked').click(function() {

     clickedButtons.push(this.value); // adds element to the array
     $(this).unbind('click'); // stop listening 

     console.log(clickedButtons);

     $("here").val(clickedButtons.join());

   });


 });
```

[**Working jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jLjh9oLm/5/)

Additional note:

- I removed all the `onclick="..."` buttons attribute from the html as it is not needed if you listen to the click event with jQuery.

-

**Edit (Toggle version)**

If you need to toggle the button values inside the array you just have to make the following edits:

FROM:

```
 clickedButtons.push(this.value); // adds element to the array
 $(this).unbind('click'); // stop listening
```

TO:

```
 var index = clickedButtons.indexOf(this.value);

 if (index === -1) 
   clickedButtons.push(this.value);  //value not found so push it
 else
   clickedButtons.splice(index, 1);   // value found so remove it
```

[**Working jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jLjh9oLm/6/)

Comment: What's the point in iterating over `$(this)` which reference to the clicked button?

Comment: @AlonEitan correct, it has no sense. I leaved that as it was from the code the OP posted. I'm editing my answer, thank you

Comment: I'll nag you again by asking: "What will happen if you click on the same button more than once"? :) But i'll also upvote your answer

Comment: as @AlonEitan  said,there is duplicate values inside array.

Comment: @AlonEitan @RIYAJKHAN correct, I'm editing my code by adding the `unbind()` function after a button is pressed. thank you again

Comment: @fbid Now value of each clicked button is inside array, but if i unclick it(e.i. click on it again) value of that button is still inside an array, and I would like it not to be.. That's also what I've tried to achieve with my code. Have any update on that? I would be really glad to accept your answer

Comment: @Ognj3n see the edit in my answer, let me know if it's ok.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks for help, I'm glad to learn from you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the working fiddle



  [$(document).ready(function() {
   var clickedButtons = new Array();
 $('button.clicked').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background','red');
     clickedButtons.push( this.value);
    $("#here").val(clickedButtons.join());
  });
```

}); ]

https://jsfiddle.net/jLjh9oLm/4/

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use **this** variable which point current

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.clicked').click(function() {
     alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```